# SQL Server database ReportServer blank

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I'm trying to troubleshoot one of the many data-driven subscriptions we have active, and everything I've read says there's more information in the ReportServer database in SQL Server. The issue is that every table in ReportServer has no data newer than 2014. Is there somewhere else subscription data would be getting written to? I've checked the logs on the C drive, but can't find a subscription ID to reference an error back to.

Comment: Whats the issue with the subscription, and whats the last run date showing in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
WITH    cte_ssrslastexecution
          AS ( SELECT   ReportPath ,
                        TimeStart ,
                        TimeEnd ,
                        DATEDIFF(DAY, TimeEnd, GETDATE()) Days ,
                        RequestType ,
                        UserName ,
                        Format
               FROM     ExecutionLog2
               WHERE    ( ReportPath LIKE @folder )
             ),
        cte_suscriptions
          AS ( SELECT   USR.UserName AS SubscriptionOwner ,
                        SUB.ModifiedDate ,
                        SUB.[Description] ,
                        SUB.EventType ,
                        SUB.DeliveryExtension ,
                        SUB.LastStatus ,
                        SUB.LastRunTime ,
                        DATEDIFF(DAY, SUB.LastRunTime, GETUTCDATE()) AS Days ,
                        SCH.NextRunTime ,
                        SCH.Name AS ScheduleName ,
                        CAT.[Path] AS ReportPath ,
                        CAT.[Description] AS ReportDescription
               FROM     dbo.Subscriptions AS SUB
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Users AS USR ON SUB.OwnerID = USR.UserID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.[Catalog] AS CAT ON SUB.Report_OID = CAT.ItemID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.ReportSchedule AS RS ON SUB.Report_OID = RS.ReportID
                                                              AND SUB.SubscriptionID = RS.SubscriptionID
                        INNER JOIN dbo.Schedule AS SCH ON RS.ScheduleID = SCH.ScheduleID 
              -- WHERE CAT.[Path] LIKE N'%Marketing%'
             ),
        cte_last
          AS ( SELECT   ReportPath ,
                        MAX(TimeStart) AS TimeStart
               FROM     ExecutionLog2
               WHERE    ( ReportPath LIKE @folder )
               GROUP BY ReportPath
             )
    SELECT  DISTINCT
            a.* ,
            CASE WHEN s.ScheduleName IS NULL THEN 'NO'
                 ELSE 'YES'
            END AS Subscriptions
    FROM    cte_ssrslastexecution a
            INNER JOIN cte_last b ON a.ReportPath = b.ReportPath
                                     AND a.TimeStart = b.TimeStart
            LEFT JOIN cte_suscriptions s ON a.ReportPath = s.ReportPath
    ORDER BY a.Days;
```